# It says that can't read the value of null, I want to put the data from the HTML and then make a raffle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did several things and I think I'm close but there is something that I don't know and I can't finish the code,I've take code from different people form here, Stackoverflow and I think there is  trash code left behind that is doing anything there, what's wrong? I did it on Dcoder.

```js
var rndList = [];
var rndList2 = [];

function GD() {
  var a = document.getElementById("MinS").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("MaxS").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("Min").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("Max").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("PrzNo").value;
  r = [a, b, c, d, e];
  return r;
}


var input = document.getElementsByClassName("o");

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    resultados = GD();
    var a = resultados[0];
    var b = resultados[1];
    var c = resultados[2];
    var d = resultados[3];
    var e = resultados[4];

    function raffle(MinS, MaxS, Min, Max, PrzNo) {
      function getRndInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < PrzNo; i++) {
        rndList.push(getRndInt(MinS, MaxS + 1));
      }
      for (i = 0; i < PrzNo; i++) {
        rndList2.push(getRndInt(Min, Max + 1));
      }
    }
    raffle(a, b, c, d, e);
    console.log("Serie: " + rndList);
    console.log("Number: " + rndList2);
  });
};
```

```css
.botton {
  border: 1px solid #2e518b;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2e518b;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted #f00;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: auto;
}

.o {}
```

```html
<form action="RifaYeah.html" method="post" name="frm" onsubmit="raffle(a, b, c, d, e)">
  <p class="center"> Mínima Serie: <input class="center o" type="number" name="MinS" id="Mins"><br> Máxima Serie: <input class="center o" type="number" name="MaxS" id="MaxS"><br> Mínimo Número: <input class="center o" type="number" name="Min" Id="Min"><br> Máximo Número:
    <input class="center o" type="number" name="Max" id="Max"><br> Cantidad de premios: <input class="center o" type="number" name="PrzNo" id="PrzNo"><br> <input class="botton center" type="submit" value="Rifar!"> </p>
</form>
```

PD: I'm a noob, I know. And I speak spanish

Comment: just letting you know that you can ask your questions in spanish here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: you try : `var a = document.getElementById("MinS").value;` while you have `id="Mins"` it is about a typo

Comment: THX U <3 now I'm figuring out why are numbers not matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only about a typo. your first `id` should be `MinS` but it was `Mins` on the HTML side.

```js
var rndList = [];
var rndList2 = [];

function GD() {
  var a = document.getElementById("MinS").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("MaxS").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("Min").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("Max").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("PrzNo").value;
  r = [a, b, c, d, e];
  return r;
}


var input = document.getElementsByClassName("o");

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    resultados = GD();
    var a = resultados[0];
    var b = resultados[1];
    var c = resultados[2];
    var d = resultados[3];
    var e = resultados[4];

    function raffle(MinS, MaxS, Min, Max, PrzNo) {
      function getRndInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < PrzNo; i++) {
        rndList.push(getRndInt(MinS, MaxS + 1));
      }
      for (i = 0; i < PrzNo; i++) {
        rndList2.push(getRndInt(Min, Max + 1));
      }
    }
    raffle(a, b, c, d, e);
    console.log("Serie: " + rndList);
    console.log("Number: " + rndList2);
  });
};
```

```css
.botton {
  border: 1px solid #2e518b;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2e518b;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted #f00;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: auto;
}

.o {}
```

```html
<form action="RifaYeah.html" method="post" name="frm" onsubmit="raffle(a, b, c, d, e)">
  <p class="center"> Mínima Serie: <input class="center o" type="number" name="MinS" id="MinS"><br> Máxima Serie: <input class="center o" type="number" name="MaxS" id="MaxS"><br> Mínimo Número: <input class="center o" type="number" name="Min" Id="Min"><br> Máximo Número:
    <input class="center o" type="number" name="Max" id="Max"><br> Cantidad de premios: <input class="center o" type="number" name="PrzNo" id="PrzNo"><br> <input class="botton center" type="submit" value="Rifar!"> </p>
</form>
```